# Как вызвать намерение установки приложения?

Tags: android, android-intent

Имеется путь к apk пакету, который нужно установить. Как заставить ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE установить пакет по этому пути ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604922/3212712) предлагают так:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```